# Crystal Sub report printing an extra line in Excel

Tags: crystal-reports

I developed a report in Crystal that has to print to Excel.

When printing the report to Excel it adds the data in the columns correctly up until the sub report. The sub report is added in the first column of the next row, then it adds a blank line, and then it adds the remaining columns in the first column on the next row.

I have aligned and resized all the fields in the main report and in the sub report to be the same height. All sections that does not need to print is suppressed in the main report and sub report.

I have removed the margins in the sub report.

I have done the right click a section and arrange lines and fit section

I have tried printing with excel formats: - Excel 97 - 2000 (Extended) and Workbook (Extended)

I don't know what to do from here.

Screenshots of  the report:

[Design View Crystal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk4VX.png)

[Printed Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpC5s.png)

[Export options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7PbC.png)

The option Excel 97-2000 does not work as it uses multiple columns in Excel for one column as in the screenshot below: (this causes issues when trying to filter or sort the Excel sheet)

[Multiple columns issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFxsR.png)

I am using Crystal Reports 2013 Support Pack 4, Version 14.1.4.1327

Comment: You mean "A_1 LVEBALANC_0" is a subreport?

Comment: No that is a normal field from the DB.
The Sub report is called LeaveTaken